Android drawer shows back arrow when open by default
I have a simple drawer in my android app. When I don't set it open by default when app starts, all the fragments shows correctly the hamburger menu to toggle the drawer.
However when I set the drawer open by default at app start, instead of the hamburger menu, it is back arrow showing (the drawer toggle works well).
How to have the same hamburger menu when the drawer is open by default?
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); //open drawer by default

//default selected activity
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit(); }

setupToolbar();

void setupToolbar(){
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
}

void setupDrawerToggle(){
mDrawerToggle = new androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.on, R.string.off);

mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

Changing getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); to false did not help.

So I just found out that when I add this line, then it is working correctly also with drawer opened by default:
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

